# PhantomXHR + CasperJS early in a page's lifecycle

Tags: ajax, phantomjs, casperjs, sinon

I am using [PhantomXHR](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomXHR) along with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org) to implement frontend functional testing along with stubbed out AJAX requests.

The faked XHR requests and stubbed responses work great in a page that is already initialized and the AJAX request is triggered by a user action such as a click or a keyup.

When trying to initialize a faked XHR request upon page load, however, I cannot get it to work. Is this a bug, or what is the recommended way of going about this?

I am using Marionette and Backbone in my SPA and upon initialization of a template, if certain conditions are met, an AJAX call is made. I cannot get PhantomXHR to fake this request no matter what I do.

I have tried initializing PhantomXHR and the faked request before calling `casper.start('http://localhost:3000/my/foo/bar')`, I have tried calling `casper.start()`, initializing the PhantomXHR and then doing `casper.open('http://localhost:3000/my/foo/bar')`, nothing seems to work. Can anyone tell me the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a scoping *and* order of operations issue. By defining the variable `fake` before CasperJS even starts and then initializing that fake to a variable in the `page.initialized` CasperJS event before I even navigate anywhere, the `fake` variable is scoped properly and is accessible to my tests.

```
var fakes = require('../base_fakes.js')
var fake = null

// Ensure that posts are being properly loaded into the UI with a stubbed XHR request
// to fetch the posts from the server
casper.test.begin('Loading stuff in the thing works', 5, function suite(test) {
  casper.start();
  casper.on('page.initialized', function(resource){
    xhr.init(casper.page, {
      libraryRoot: '../../../node_modules/phantomxhr/'
    })

    fake = xhr.fake(fakes.things_index)
  })

  casper.then(function() {
    casper.open('http://localhost:3000')
    this.wait(2000, function() {
      console.log("test")
      console.log(fake.count());
      this.capture('screenshot1.png')
    })
  })
```